# Can we put disable property to the icons based on condition in angular

Tags: angular

Can we put disable property to the icons based on condition in angular..Or is there any method to acheive this?

eg :  `<i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>&nbsp;`

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes then show your attempt!

Comment: Which kind of icons are you talking about? Are you talking about properties (component properties in the .ts) or attributes (Html tags in the .Html template)? The answer to your question is "Yes", but we really cannot determine what is the exact meaning of the question.

Comment: Should the "icon" look different if "disabled"? Or do just want a (click)-handler to not be executed when disabled? The second part can easily be handled with a flag in your .ts-file

Comment: @Chund "icon" should look different...If it is disabled..

Comment: @user11759028 you can set class "disabled" to your icon like [class.disabled]="condition" and add class description to scss like ".disabled{opacity: 50%}".

Comment: @user11759028 Glad to hear :) you can vote for my comment at least.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which library you're using and whether it supports that out of the box or not.

[**`@angular/material`**](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api#MatButton), for example, supports it out of the box.

Here's an example:

```
<mat-card-actions>
  <button 
    mat-icon-button 
    [disabled]="count === 0" 
    aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon"
    (click)="count = count - 1">
    <mat-icon>remove_circle_outline</mat-icon>
  </button>
  {{ count }}
  <button 
    mat-icon-button 
    [disabled]="count === 3" 
    aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon"
    (click)="count = count + 1">
    <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-condition-on-disabled-property?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.html) for your ref.

### What if you don't want to use a library like `@angular/material`

If you're not using a library like `@angular/material`, then you can always use `ngClass` and set classes conditionally on elements.

You'd create a CSS class like this:

```
.disabled {
  cursor: none;
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And then apply it on the icons conditionally like this:

```
<a 
  href="javascript:void(0)" 
  class="card-link minus"
  [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': count === 0 }"
  (click)="count = count - 1">
  <svg class="svg-circleplus" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="none" stroke-width="7.5"></circle>
    <line x1="32.5" y1="50" x2="67.5" y2="50" stroke-width="5"></line>
  </svg>
</a>
<span class="card-link">
  {{ count }}
</span>
<a 
  href="javascript:void(0)" 
  class="card-link plus"
  [ngClass]="{ 'disabled': count === 3 }"
  (click)="count = count + 1">
  <svg class="svg-circleplus" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="none" stroke-width="7.5"></circle>
    <line x1="32.5" y1="50" x2="67.5" y2="50" stroke-width="5"></line>
    <line x1="50" y1="32.5" x2="50" y2="67.5" stroke-width="5"></line>
  </svg>
</a>
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icon-button-disable-with-css-conditionally?file=app/timepicker-basic.html) for your ref.

**PS:** You might want to take additional measures to make sure that the CSS styles are not overridden by pro users by navigating to Dev Tools and changing them manually.